# Better use Vector to get distances

Tags: vector, vector-graphics

In some instances of Vectors to get the distance between two points, I've check that i need only to subtraction.
But another examples has used the subtraction with square root.
I'd like to know is what the difference!

```
Distance = |P-E| = |(3,3)-(1,2)| = |(2,1)| = sqrt(22+12) = sqrt(5) = 2.23

Distance = |P-E| = |(3,3)-(1,2)| = |(2,1)|
```

Tks

Comment: I don't follow your formulas - are you claiming that `22 + 12 == 5`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as the one true distance on a vector space. Generally distance denotes a distance function `d(x,y)` (where x and y are the 2 vectors) that obeys some rules that probably seem obvious:

- for any x,y `d(x,y) >= 0`
- `d(x,y) == 0` if and only if `x==y`
- for any x,y `d(x,y) == d(y,x)`
- for any x,y,z `d(x,y) <= d(x,z) + d(z,y)`

One such distance function is the Euclidean distance (with the square root), but there are others such as the 1-norm (also known as the taxicab or manhattan distance) which is sum of the absolute values of the differences in coordinates or the Hamming distance (number of coordinates which differ).

Depending on what you are doing different distance functions may be useful. The euclidean distance is probably what you think of as the 'normal' distance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to use the square root method. By just subtracting, you are getting another vector which isn't representing a distance - it's representing the point you'd end up at.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), then your first example is correct (I am interpreting `22` and `12` as meaning "2 squared" and "1 squared" respectively).

Answer (score 0):

We use the notation |vector| at school to [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) a vector. What you do is basically "translate" a vector into a [scalar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_%28mathematics%29).